# Define a lambda creation

Tags: c++, c++14

How can I make a general lambda creator, e.g, something like this:

```
#define LAMBDA(f, args...)
```

to create lambda:

```
[&](){ return f(args...); };
```

So I can do:

```
int main
{
   int a, b, c, d;
   auto lambda4 = LAMBDA(foo4, a, b , c, d);

   int e, f;
   auto lambda2 = LAMBDA(foo2, e, f);


}
```

I'm restricted to using C++14.

Comment: That's not beautification, that's obfuscation :-) Please don't mess with macros unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Why not use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) if you really want to avoid lambda syntax?

Comment: need that lambda alive, cannot use bind, function is a nice idea but want it easier

Comment: C++11/C++14 doesn't make much sense. Anything that works in C++11 will work in C++14, so I've edited the question to specify the most recent C++ revision that you're able to use.

Comment: It may look prettier to you, but please remember that coding is a *language*, so it's intended to be read by others as well. And nobody else will understand what that syntax means. If you want to write C++, then learn to read C++. Don't bend the language to your vision of what it *should have* been.

Comment: The desired code is ugly like a few things in life.

Comment: Can you do some version of this [Yes you can](https://godbolt.org/z/x4cec1h6W) and I feel dirty for even linking that because it's pointless and the arguments cause problems because the arguments are still going to get copied unless you want real pain. Just use `std::bind`, please

Comment: I voted to reopen the question since I don't see how it is opinion-based. The question asks for implementing a specific syntax. It should have additional requirements given in the comments added to it, but otherwise seems clear and well-defined to me. There is already a good answer. Whether or not that syntax is desirable is irrelevant to the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried using function pointers or function objects?  In many instances, a lambda can be replaced by a pointer to a function or a function object (functor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use macros for this. It just obfuscates the code.

[The best solution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front):

```
auto l4 = std::bind_front(foo4, a, b, c, d);
```

But that's C++20.

With C++14 you can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). However you state you cannot use it.

We are then left with implementing a bind full function. Getting one off the ground with copy semantics is pretty simple:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto bind_full(F f, Args... args)
    noexcept (noexcept (f(args...)))
{
    return [=]() {
        return f(args...);
    };
}
```

```
auto foo_bind = bind_full(foo4, a, b, c, d);
    
return foo_bind()
```

Optimizing it for forward semantics is deceptively hard though. You can't do it with a lambda, you need a custom functor with overloaded function call operators.

Comment: "_Optimizing it for forward semantics is deceptively hard though._": Because OP can't use pack expansions in init-captures without C++20 or why specifically would that be an issue?

Comment: @user17732522 no. It's because the lambda stores references to the `bind_full` arguments. If inside the lambda body you do `std::forward<Args>(args)` is incorrect as deciding on passing as lvalue or rvalue should be decided on the value category of the lambda itself at the moment of call invocation not on the value category of the `bind_full` arguments.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes that is an issue. I was thinking of forwarding the `bind_full` arguments into the captures of the lambda (like `std::bind_front` does). You are currently always copying.